# classes instantiated by cmd line arg import conflicts

Tags: python, class, data-structures, importerror, instantiation

I have a dictionary data structure holding two classes where the key is a string representing the argument I am passing to my app.py and the value is the actual class, in the following format

```
from my package import ClassA
from my_other_package import ClassB
from my_other_package import ClassZ
DICT = { 
    "class_a": ClassA 
    "class_b": ClassB 
    ...
    "class_z": ClassZ
```

In my app.py I have a logic in place which performs a callback and returns within app.py, the class instantiated after the argument is taken and parsed from command line.
So when i execute the following command i get my object created.

`python3 app.py class_a`

Now the problem is the following: since my data structure holds both classes definitions (and will certainty grow to support different use cases), when the DICT{} is imported in the app.py and initialized, both ClassA and ClassB dependencies are checked on runtime.

Let's say for example that ClassA includes an import error due to a pip dependency not defined also ClassB will be affected and will not be initialized, returning an import error due to a missing pip library installed, but for the other class which is not involved in the current setup.

Eventually, I would like still to be able to instantiate classes using the following logic dynamically, but I would also like to be able to split it in a way that ClassA and ClassB would not affect each other from whatever runtime error would occur.

I thought if the namespace topic could come into the game and a different approach would help to solve the issue, as well as creating an ad-hoc import strategy using __ init __.py or also completely reworking the structure but I can't figure out an optimal way
Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like you only want to import `ClassA` if `class_a` is the command-line argument. You'll need to use `importlib` to support dynamically importing a module.

Comment: The thing is that I need a data structure to hold the references, since the classes I would import may grow exponentially so I need a way how to hash the argument key to the class value. Do you see this use case valid for using a dictionary and create a logic around importlib to instantiate a class? Or better to re design the way how I hold this reference? I am currently thinking just to a dict but maybe there is a better way to do that while working with importlib